# What is difference between Dispatch Queue Priority and QoS in Dispatch Queue?

Tags: ios, dispatch-queue

is there any difference between DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH and user-interactive for QoS in Dispatch Queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has deprecated Dispatch queue priority from iOS 8.0 instead of that we can use Quality of service.

So Basically QOS and priority does same thing.

Answer (score -1):

From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatch_queue_priority_high):

> Items dispatched to the queue run at high priority; the queue is scheduled for execution before any default priority or low priority queue.
>
> This constant maps to the QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED class.

So, they are not entirely equivalent.

Comment: Hi Cristik, when to give priority or QoS to distach queue?

Comment: @nuttekar the documentation should give you the best answer to this. If you can't find it in the documentation you can ask another question on SO.

Comment: what will happen if i give high priority with background as a QoS?